# why Facebook Like box showing empty content, and count is not saved

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-like

I have a Facebook [application](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Cody-Style/159581120745430?sk=app_225554037471298) with multiple Like buttons on it.

When you click on some Like, the box is not showing the proper content, seams empty, and the count is not saved. Try randomly a few on the linked page.

The Facebook [linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Ffreeforall.epixhd.com%2Fcalendar%2Fview%2F3) on that URL is reporting everything fine. I have setup the meta tags in the page, as you can see [here](http://freeforall.epixhd.com/calendar/view/3).

The empty box looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you expect to show up in that box? To me it seems like it was intened to look that way.

Comment: It should show up the image + title + description of the page as it looks usually on other sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook's [example Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) doesn't show an image or description; the shows up on my profile when I click it. Your Like Button [here](http://freeforall.epixhd.com/calendar/view/3) behaves the same way, and the Like count is working correctly.